# AJAX GET Url Parameter and pass to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

My user will be access `../verify.php?code=1228119j8dwq8dj218`

and i want the `1228119j8dwq8dj218` passed to `/verify_action.php`

I've tried something like below but it says `code` is undefined,

when i tried to place my `verify-action.php` script in the `verify.php` and change `url:"verify-action.php"` to `url:"verify.php"` it working perfectly but causing my success and error message not showing properly

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"verify-action.php",
                method:"GET",
                data:{code:code},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data.error !== '')
                    {
                        $('#message').html(data.error);
                    }
                    if(data.success != '')
                    {
                        $('#message').html(data.success);
                    }
                }
            })
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
$error = '';
$success = '';

if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{
    $object->query = "
    UPDATE user_table 
    SET email_verify = 'Yes' 
    WHERE user_verification_code = '".$_GET["code"]."'
    ";

    $object->execute();

    $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">Your Email has been Verified</div>';
}else{
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Verify Error. Please Contact Administrator</div>';
}

$output = array(
            'error'     =>  $error,
            'success'   =>  $success
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `../verify.php?code:1228119j8dwq8dj218` surely you mean `../verify.php?code=1228119j8dwq8dj218`? Need to use `=` instead of `:` in the url if you expect in PHP to access it via `$_GET["code"]`.

Comment: I'm sorry i mean `=` but the problem is, i need to pass the value to verify_action.php

Comment: You'd need to get the URL parameter first, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/how-to-get-url-parameter-using-jquery-or-plain-javascript

Comment: ohh ok i see, its worked

Answer (score 1):

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var code = urlParams.get('code');
```

Simple solution is just to get the URL parameter using that script
Thanks to @broomber